# Blink $scope element outside ng-view

Tags: angularjs

I'm new in angular but have some basic.
I build menu with a number of items in the list. The menu is in different controller.
Each time I change a view (ng-view) by route the number of items blink - I suspect that t $scope is refresh. And this is ok, but I want to refresh the number when I add new item, note everytime.

My controller:

List I use for ng-view, Naviagtion use like simple controller.

```
function List($scope, $location, Inbox) {

   $scope.inbox = Inbox.query();

};

function Navigation($scope, Inbox) {

   $scope.inbox_number = Inbox.getcount();

}
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="Navigation">
  {{ inbox_number.count }}
</div>

<div ng-view></div>
```

Maybe I'm doing something wrong but how to achieve a structure like:
(navigation controller)

(MENU)

**Customers: 3**

(LIST VIEW)

1. Customer 1
2. Customer 2
3. Customer 3

And when i add new customer than my menu will refresh, when i change view (list view -> add customer) my menu will not refresh ?